# How to build specific multiple targets parallelly using make?

Tags: makefile, build, parallel-processing, target

There are three source files. Each source files are corresponding targets. For example, the target of a.cpp is a, b.cpp is b, and c.cpp is c.

```
src/a.cpp
    b.cpp
    c.cpp
build/
```

I can build the targets parallelly using `-j` option.

For example,

```
cd build
make -j3
```

target a, b, and c build parallelly.

Is there any way to specify some of targets and parallel build ?

For example

```
make -j2 a b
```

Unfortunately, it works sequentially. First, build `a` and then build `b`.
I want to build only `a` and `b` parallelly.

I tried the following approach.

```
make a&
make b&
wait
```

However, the return code of the `wait` is the last finished waiting target. That means if `make a&` finished with failure and then `make b&` successfully finished,  the return code of `wait` is 0.
I want to stop building process if any of make are failure.

Is there any good way ?

Comment: Generally examples like -j2 or -j3 above should work launching jobs in parallel; are there any dependencies connecting those targets?  posting the Makefile could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, it works sequentially

That is not true, as you could see from writing a small test:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: one two

one two:
        @echo start $@
        @sleep 2
        @echo stop $@

$ make
start one
stop one
start two
stop two

$ make -j2
start one
start two
stop one
stop two

$ make -j2 one two
start one
start two
stop one
stop two
```

As you can see even when providing specific targets on the command line, they are run in parallel.  If you are not seeing this behavior then there's something about your makefiles that is materially different than what you've described in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was going to wrong way. The Makefile is generated by cmake at the case I reported. I had misunderstood that `-j` option prevents multiple targets. I still have problem that I reported. But now, I understand that the unexpected behavior is NOT caused by make but caused by cmake generated Makefile. I guess that I misuse something about cmake. I will investigate it.